# Can i use a use variable in Fullcalendar for render events data?

Tags: php, wordpress, fullcalendar, boilerplate

I am using Fullcalendar for my event calendar plugin in WordPress. I am using the WordPress `wp_localize_script` function so that I can use my PHP variables as JavaScript variables. Here is my localization code

```
    // - json items -
    $jsonevents[]= array(
        'title' => $post->post_title,
        'allDay' => false, // $stime,
        'start' => $st,
        'end' => $et,
        'url' => get_post_type_archive_link('event')
        );
    endforeach;
    else :
    endif;

$sawon =  json_encode($jsonevents);
wp_localize_script( 'fullcalendar', 'localized_script',$sawon);
```

and  here is my jquery script

```
$(function() {
    ("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        header :{
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
        events : localized_script
    });
});
```

My Fullcalendar does not show any events, but `localized_script` is available in my browser. The console also shows an error called "Failed to load resource" with my `localized_script value`. What is the problem and what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$jsonevents= array(
        'title' => 'post_title',
        'allDay' => false, // $stime,
        'start' => '2017-01-01',
        'end' => '2017-01-03',
        'url' => 'archive link'
        );

$sawon =  json_encode($jsonevents);

wp_localize_script($this->plugin_name, 'local_script',
    array( 
        'ajax_url' => wp_make_link_relative(admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )),
        'ajax_nonce' =>$sawon,
        )
    );
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75czr.png) is the localized script result in browser console.